# Why can't I delete my (unaccepted) answers on my Android device?

Tags: support, android-app, mobile-web, vote-to-delete

I am looking for a way to delete my own answers that I think are not useful any more or just are of extremely poor quality. I'm using the Android app, and also tried to delete the answers on the mobile web version in my

When searched for the way to delete my answers, many topics say about "Delete" button that appears under my answers, but I don't see such a button (no matter if using the app or a browser on my mobile phone, I see "Edit", "Share" or "Flag" there).

Are the answers about "Delete" button out of date due to change of rules of deletion of answers here or am I just missing something? Is the proper amount of reputation points needed to see such a button (when asking this question I have about 1600 points)? The answers I want to delete are not marked as accepted.

I know that I can flag my answer to get moderator's intervention and describe that I wanted to delete my own answer, but I'm not sure if it is the only/proper way to delete my answer and to wait then until it is reviewed by others.

Here is one of sample answers ([How to get String between last two underscore](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48002930/8116173)), this is the only option I see when tapping "More" button:

[image: Screenshot of sample answer]

I tried to use these 3 dots many times before and in my mobile browser, tried to change to Desktop view. This keeps redirecting me back to the Stack Exchange app.

Comment: (Also see [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221) for the exact rules).

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thank you for your help, please have a look at comment that I made to the answer to this question,I'm sorry that I took your time, it seems that I didn't check all  possible ways deeply enough.

Comment: That the Android app doesn't let you delete posts is really annoying, and with the current state of development for the mobile apps that's not going to change any time soon. That you can't also do so via the mobile browser because the app intercepts SE URLs is even more annoying. We can update your question to include what happens when you try in the mobile browser, and update the answer to show how to remedy those parts; those together make an excellent post here on Meta to point other victims of the same malaise to.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Feel free to make any edit you think of to make this post any better as I may not use the proper words when describing what is going on here "under the hood". I may try to take some screenshots if you think that they're necessary, but I'm afraid that I can do it after few hours from now as I don't have much time right now :-/

Comment: @MartijnPieters Oh, now when looking at edit history I see that much of editing work is done actually, it looks much better now so thank you. If you want me to provide some additional informations or screenshots, I can do it, but a bit later, just tell what would be needed.

Comment: Feel free to add further improvements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't delete posts from the android app, unfortunately.

You need to be on the full site to do stuff like that. Press "... More", then "Open in browser". There you will find the *Delete* link.

If in the browser you are redirected back to the Stack Exchange app, go into the Application Settings, find the app, and remove its default Supported URLs to prevent this.

Comment: You're right, I'm sorry for taking time of you all. I tried to use these 3 dots many times before and tried to change to Desktop view, but it keep redirected me to StackExchange app, which seems to not allow a deletion of answers too. I uninstalled this app and it then forced to see stackoverflow.com in Desktop view. In this view, now I see this button, but I don't really understand the purpose of not allowing user to delete his answer through mobile app/mobile view. It seems that I didn't put proper effort to check it myself.

Comment: It seems that I didn't put proper effort to check it myself. It seems that I need to flag this question to be deleted as it seems to be really dumb :-/. Again, I'm sorry for taking time of you all.

Comment: @PrzemysławMoskal That's an Android problem. Go into the Application Settings, find the SE app, and remove its default Supported URLs.

Comment: Thank you, that solved the problem.